# What mathematical function could be used to simulate this sound effect?

Tags: discrete-signals, sound

I have this [sound effect](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bKE3_zRs2d4nq9CBND8uZlwHwHUzpN-s/view?usp=sharing) which by the way if anyone could give me its name, I would really appreciate it. And after loading it into matlab/octave (don't worry this isn't a programming question) using the following commands:

```
[x, fs] = audioread("Path To File");
plot(length(x(:,1)),x)
sound(x,fs) % To hear the sound
```

I get the following:
[image: plot]
Could anyone tell me what mathematical function I could use to simulate this?

Comment: So you have a recording of a sound, you don't know what it is called or how to model it, but you want to do some simulation with it? I'm not following this

Comment: I think you should be clearer about what you mean when you ask how to simulate it. Do you wish to generate the same sound? a similar sound? If it is the same sound just take this one. If you want a similar sound you have to specify how similar. you can only define how similar if can define the sound. If you do not know how it is called or what it is, how can you generate something similar?

Comment: @havakok I want to generate one as similar to this one as possible. I got it off free from the internet but I want to be able to know how to generate one as similar as possible. It's a mere curiosity.

Comment: @daviddavid this is not a sound. this is a drawing of a function that could be a sound. It could also be any other signal. You do not know what is the sound, all you know is that you have it. Generating a sound could be a complex task involving understanding that sound's features which you don't. No one can help you if you don't know what you want to generate.

Comment: @havakok I want to find a mathematical function that closely simulates the drawing of the sound. I do not plan on using regression of whatever sort or similar. I can then play the sound using the function using a similar version of the program mentioned above. I plan on recreating it synthetically not in real life

Comment: @daviddavid, I am not sure you understand the problems with your questions.

Comment: @havakok At least, I think I do. Would you care to explain further?

Comment: @havakok Are you trying to tell me that it's impossible to reverse engineer a sound?

Comment: @daviddavid , I am trying to tell you that the task you are attempting is not well defined (at least as I understand from your question and comments). You, first, have to determine what you want to do in a higher level. "I want to generate one as similar to this one as possible.". Well, you can generate exactly the same sound by comping it. I am guessing you want something different that sounds similar. Well, what is similar? Do you have any similarity measure? Who said there is any function which can generate this sound? Do you have more examples? The information you give insufficient.

Comment: Generating sound tasks can be very complicated and are task-dependent. Generating speech is a well-researched task which attempts at characterizing such a sound and generating something with the same characteristics. Otherwise, you can use data-driven methods (neural network for example). For this,  you need many examples and not 1  (maybe 200 for starters). If we go over to music signal generation, we get a totally different task, also well researched with other solutions. Here, also, we characterize the sound and generate something with the same characteristics or use more examples.

Comment: Many other tasks focus on the same principles. You don't even know what is your sound. You have one example. Read @Engineer comment. There is not enough information to help you.

Comment: @havakok I perfectly understand what you are trying to say. I just thought that if you could know that a sound was created by a sine wave just by looking at its plot then you could (maybe it would be a little harder) extrapolate this to other sounds such as this one. I just thought that maybe someone with experience on creating sound effects could recognize it.